# validation of input element before cloning

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation

I have group of input elements in my form. The user have to add rows to insert multiple values for different date transaction. Now before adding another row, I have to validate the date field and amount field.

My form:

```
<div id="content_add" class="d-none">
    <div class="row i_bike_servicing">
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bike_servicing[from_place][]">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 ">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bike_servicing[from_date][]">
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bike_servicing[to_place][]">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 ">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bike_servicing[to_date][]">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 ">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bike_servicing[expenses][]">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-2 ">From Location</div>
    <div class="col-md-1 ">From Date</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 ">To Location</div>
    <div class="col-md-1 ">To Date</div>
    <div class="col-md-1 ">Expenses</div>
    <div class="col-md-1 ">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" id="add_servicing" type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> add &nbsp;</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content_show">
    <div class="row i_bike_servicing">
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bike_servicing[from_place][]">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 ">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bike_servicing[from_date][]">
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bike_servicing[to_place][]">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 ">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bike_servicing[to_date][]">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 ">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bike_servicing[expenses][]">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$('#add_servicing').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let html_clone = $('#content_add').html();
        $('#content_show').append(html_clone);
    });
</script>
```

When the user presses the add button, I have to check for the added row, whether **from date is smaller than to date or not** and **expenses should be always be less than 2500** for each row. How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve this?

Comment: I don't know from where to start. Please help. Thank you!